# Viber icon broken?

Tags: icons

I'm getting errors in showing viber icons. Can anyone help me with this?

Menu:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DeS9.jpg

Panel:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1NXq.jpg

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a script to run viber:

`sudo nano /usr/local/bin/viber-start`

put into it:

`#!/bin/bash
VIBER_USE_LIBAPPINDICATOR=1 XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity  /opt/viber/Viber`

2. Make it executable

`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/viber-start`

3. Open viber.desktop
   `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/viber.desktop`

and replace the contents of a file to

`[Desktop Entry]
Name=Viber
Comment=Viber VoIP and messenger
Exec=viber-start
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/viber.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Network;Application;
Path=`

4. Logout the system